# Submit data to MySQL database from android app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm trying to write form which make reservation and save it mysql. So there are 4-5 field in the form `name, phone, email, comment, time, date, table, people`. I must tell that I'm very new in Java and Android and don't know how to do this but I'm trying. Also I think that code is really mess right now so I need some help. 
Here is the code so far of `Reservation.java`

```
public class Reservation extends Activity implements
                             OnClickListener {

String Name;
String Email;
String Phone;
String Comment;
String DateTime;
String Time;
String Table;
String numberOfPeople;

private EditText editText1, editText3, editText2, editText4, txtDate, txtTime;
private Button btnCalendar, btnTimePicker, btnMenues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reservation);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

    btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);
    btnTimePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTimePicker);
    btnMenues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMenues);


    btnMenues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Name = editText1.getText().toString();
            Phone = editText3.getText().toString();
            Email = editText2.getText().toString();
            Comment = editText4.getText().toString();
            DateTime = txtDate.getText().toString();
            DateTime = txtTime.getText().toString();
            new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);
        }
    }); 
}

class SummaryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private void postData(String name, String email, String phone,
            String comment, String date, String table, String numberofpeople) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://link.to.server.com/saveReservation.php");

        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Phone", phone));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Comment", comment));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", date));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Table", table));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numberOfPeople", numberofpeople));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        postData(Name, Email, Phone, Comment, DateTime, Time, Table );
        return null;
    }
 }
}
```

Currently the error that I get is

> The type Reservation must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)
>   Update:

And how to save date and time in database in one row or two? If is one row how to make it this in android side?

UDPATE2:
How to implement now `btnCalendar, btnTimePicker` I have them in the `reservation.xml` and they are in form. I must implement date and time picker in this code?

Comment: just remove the implements onclicklistner statement from your class definition

Comment: Error is crystal clear you are saying that Reservation is going to implement OnClickListener, it has the only method called onClick(View), which you need to implement. If you cant do that, try to keep an empty implementation or define the class as abstract or get rid of OnClickListener as a whole if its not used anywhere.

Comment: Ok, I've removed onclicklistener from class definition.

Comment: Please check my second `update` of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `implements OnClickListener` but you do not over ride `onClick(View view)` method of onclicklistener interface which is mandatory. So please override method first and remove on `click listener` from `oncreate` method.

See below link for more information:-

https://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/how-to-implements-onclicklistener-for-a-view-item-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Your class implements onClick listener however you lack the method.

Either remove `implement` statement or override the method

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your logcat is here:

```
public class Reservation extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

You are implementing `OnClickListener` and then you are implementing an anonymous `onClickListener` in your  `btnMenues`. Remove your `implements OnClickListener` and the error will go away.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is

```
public class Reservation extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

just remove

```
implements OnClickListener
```

You don't need this